# Can an activation-locked MacBook ever be unlocked by a new owner?

Tags: macbook-pro, activation-lock

There is a reputable seller on eBay selling a 2017 MacBook Pro that is locked with an activation lock. I'm a Windows guy looking for a MacBook and so this is new to me. If I buy this MacBook Pro, can it be unlocked? Would a new hard drive do the trick? Is it possible that it could be unlocked but stolen so it won't work no matter what I do? Thanks!

Comment: If the seller cannot supply the activation unlock then they are not reputable.

Comment: @SolarMike does this imply that the laptop is a brick then?

Comment: @acidgate There's nothing implied.  It *is* a brick.  Apple will remove Activation Lock on proof of ownership.  An eBay invoice is not proof of ownership.

Comment: Apple require "proof of ownership". That is not the same as "proof of purchase" in this case. If the seller could provide that, they'd have had it unlocked already.

Comment: Well, Mike's comment was an implication that it's a brick since he never actually said it. But OK! Got it! It's a permanent brick that is only good for parts. I'll offer him pocket change for it.